# Linux disk usage of files that match expression

Tags: regex, linux, du

I have a mounted hard-drive with multi-users like this:

```
/HDD1/user1
/HDD1/user2
/HDD1/user3
```

I'd like to look in each user's folder, find all the files that match an expression (say, `"*.txt"`), and then sum the space used by all those files, and report it on a per user base:

```
user1: x bytes
user2: y bytes
user3: z bytes
```

I found the directories of all the files with:

```
find /HDD1/ -name "*.txt" | rev | cut -d"/" -f2- | rev | uniq > txtfiles.dat
```

I thought I'd use a loop to go through each line in `txtfiles.dat` calculating the disk usage in each folder, but this seems very cumbersome. Is there a neater way to do this? Something like a `du` that looks in each user's folder but only counting the files that match an expression?

Comment: Hint: `du -ac $(find . -name '*.txt')`

Answer (score 3):

`du` takes a list, and will size individual files if given the `-a` option and produce a total with the `-c` option.

In bash shell `$(cmd)` is the output of running `cmd`.

So, putting all that together, to get the sizes of all the .txt files, one could run:

`du -ac $(find . -name '*.txt')`

Answer (score 1):

```
find /HDD1/ -name "*.txt" -print0 | du -ch --files0-from -
```

Explanation: the `find` command takes care of filtering the file set, and specifying `-print0` makes the output NUL-terminated.

The `find` output is piped to `du`. Specifying `--files0-from -` indicates that file paths are read in a NUL-terminated stream from STDIN. Finally, `-ch` instructs `du` to add a grand total line, in human-readable form.

If all you want is the total, you can pipe the result to `tail -1`:

```
find /HDD1/ -name "*.txt" -print0 | du -ch --files0-from - | tail -1
```

Comment: This will be the total in each subdir of HDD1 or total total?

Comment: @James: This would give the total within HDD1, but you could easily wrap it in a `for` loop to calculate the sum per directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each user and sum the sizes like so:

```
for username in `ls /HDD1/`; do
  find $username -iname *.txt -printf '%s\n' | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}' -
done
```

The outer loop is for the users, then the find does the searching for files and prints their sizes out, and finally awk sums up all the sizes and prints out the result.

Comment: Does this need to be in bash? I'm using zsh at the moment (but can change easily if necessary). I'm confused as to where the variable ```username``` comes into the code.

Comment: you forgot the directory arg to find. also -printf needs a newline in the format.

Comment: I don't know zsh, but the only bash thing is the for-loop so you can convert that easily. I forgot to put $username into find, thanks to @meuh for that! However, -printf doesn't need a newline since it's going into awk and awk just needs any whitespace.

Comment: yes, awk works with whitespace, but you are using $1 and there is only 1 field 1 on each line, so you need to have each number on a newline, or sum over all the fields of one very long line (using $i for  i=1...NF).

Answer (score 1):

The find command (on most systems) can print the size of a file in bytes.
You can then just total this, eg with awk.

```
for userdir in /HDD1/*
do find "$userdir" -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%s\n' |
   awk -v u=$(basename "$userdir") '
        {tot+=$1}
        END{print u ": " tot " bytes"}
   '
done
```

This provides the output format you asked for (user1: x bytes).
If the number of bytes is a bit huge, divide by 1000 or 1024 to get kilo or
kibi bytes etc.  (in the awk print tot/1000 instead of tot).

Answer (score 0):

I pulled together bits and pieces from all your answers into this:

```
for n in /HDD1/*
  do
  uname=$(echo $n | cut -d'/' -f4)
  space=$(find /HDD1/$uname -name "*.txt" -print0 | du -ch --files0- from - | tail -1)
  echo $uname: $space
done
```

Which seems to be working fine. Thanks for all your input.